# Input Pattern Accepting Only With Space

Tags: html, validation, input

I've only just started working with `pattern` and would like to know how I can validate an `<input type="text" />` to only accept the value if there is also a space in the value?

Comment: If you just started working with the pattern attribute of an input. I would stop there, until IE gets there crap together and stops supporting ie10 and below (some time at the beginning of next year) you will find that most ie browsers do not support this, so why have html5 validation? Do it in javascript instead, a little extra work but it will be cross browser friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on what you consider a space: do you refer to a white space? a tab? a new line? all of the above?

If what you want to match is only the white space (like when you press the space bar), you could use an expression like `.*[ ].*`:

- `.*` means any character 0 or more times.
- `[ ]` means a blank space.

Here is a demo:

```html
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="text" value="" pattern=".*[ ].*" required />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

If what you want to match is any whitespace (space bar, new line, tab, etc.), use `\s`. But notice that the characters matched by it may depend on the regex flavor ([source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)).

In that case, the code would be like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="text" value="" pattern=".*[\s].*" required />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```